# Displaying information above call screen

Tags: android

I'd like to display additional information about caller from LDAP server when receiving phone call.

I learned I can't display `Dialog` (and Toast is too short) from `Service`. So I created special `Activity` for this, but sometimes, the call `Activity` is started after my `Activity`, and it hides it. So, is there some way to reliably start my LDAP `Activity` **after** system call `Activity` is displayed?

If there isn't, I guess I'll do something like application [Adaffix](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.adaffix.android) (see the second screenshot) is doing and will display it as *overlay*. I learned it's done using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`, but from the code I've seen, I have no clue how to use it. If someone can provide me code to display white rectangle with some text on top of the screen, I'll be very glad.

Or is there some other "proper" way to do it? I have no intentions to implementing my own call screen!

Comment: did you figure out a solution yet? if so please post it

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here that call screen is overriding your Activity. you need to override the call screen.

You can override the call screen by putting delay before you start your activity.The delay will be around will be 500 ms and it can be less or greater that. You need to test it and check at which delay you are getting your desired result.

Comment: Well, this might work, but it's not exactly proper solution, using some _magic_ delay constant, right?

Comment: did you figure out a solution yet? if so please post it

Comment: Nope, just used the delay. :/